# LINQ to Objects, how to update items within List in place?

Tags: c#, linq

I currently have the following working code. It is painfully slow however. I know that passing the holdings as a query rather than as a list might simplify and speed up things, but for various reasons this is not possible.

How can I update the list of holdings in place, without creating a new list? Other suggestions to improve the code?

```
internal List<DailyHoldingItem> TransformHoldingItemsToCurrency(List<DailyHoldingItem> holdings,string toCurrency)
        {
        //TODO - how to do this calculation in place, without creating a new list?
        var query = (from holding in holdings
                     from fxRateHolding in amdw.FXRates
                     from fxRateToCur in amdw.FXRates
                     where
                     fxRateHolding.BaseCurrency == holding.Currency &&
                     fxRateToCur.BaseCurrency == toCurrency &&
                     fxRateHolding.ValueDate == holding.Date &&
                     fxRateToCur.ValueDate == holding.Date
                     select new { holding, fxRateHolding, fxRateToCur });

        return query.Select(dhi =>
        {
            decimal factor = dhi.fxRateToCur.Value / dhi.fxRateHolding.Value;
            dhi.holding.MarketValue *= factor;
            dhi.holding.Fee *= factor;
            dhi.holding.Remuneration *= factor;
            return dhi.holding;
        }).ToList();

    }
```

Comment: Generally you wouldn't use LINQ to edit an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well for one thing you can speed things up using joins, and only evaluating the valid "target" currencies once:

```
var targetRates = amdw.FXRates
                      .Where(rate => rate.BaseCurrency == toCurrency)
                      .ToList();

var query = from holding in holdings
            join fxRateHolding in amdw.FXRates
              on new { holding.Currency, holding.Date } equals
                 new { Currency = fxRateHolding.BaseCurrency, 
                       Date = fxRateHolding.ValueDate }
            join fxRateToCur in targetRates
              on holding.Date equals fxRateToCur.ValueDate
            select new { holding, fxRateHolding, fxRateToCur };
```

Personally I *wouldn't* try to update the list in place and I *wouldn't* mutate the existing holdings (as you currently do in your `Select` call). Mutating existing values tends to make your code harder to reason about - which is why LINQ is *designed* to be used in a more functional way.

Comment: Thanks. Nice to see the syntax of the joins, I didn't know how to do it on more than one column. I used this solution and then updated using a foreach on the query, like the answer from Ufuk suggested. It solved the problem, the speed of the query was now more or less instantaneous.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use LINQ when updating objects. LINQ is supposed to be side-effect free, you should use it to get the items you want to change then do a foreach on them.

```
foreach(var dhi in query)
{
    decimal factor = dhi.fxRateToCur.Value / dhi.fxRateHolding.Value;
    dhi.holding.MarketValue *= factor;
    dhi.holding.Fee *= factor;
    dhi.holding.Remuneration *= factor;
}
```

You could also use ForEach function defined on `List<T>` like this.

```
query.ToList().ForEach(dhi =>
        {
            decimal factor = dhi.fxRateToCur.Value / dhi.fxRateHolding.Value;
            dhi.holding.MarketValue *= factor;
            dhi.holding.Fee *= factor;
            dhi.holding.Remuneration *= factor; 
        });
```

Like Jeff Mercado pointed out in comments, it's not a good idea to make a list just to call `ForEach()` on it.

Comment: It has to be a list to start with, from OP's code you can see it's not a list yet where updating occurs.

Comment: The point being, use an actual `foreach` loop instead of converting some collection to a list just so you could use that method.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do it in SQL, just note that not everyone will expect side affects in LINQ, but after all C# is not a functional language.

Here is what you could do:

- For updating a single property just do:

  `from a in ab select a.prop = newVal;`
- For updating multiple properties, you have the following options:

  1. Split the updates in multiple LINQ queries, each updating a single property (obviously not the best idea)
  2. Do the following `from a in ab select new { x = a.prop = newVal, y = a.prop2 = newVal2 };`
  3. In a LINQ method chain (but not in a query expression) you could do `ab.Select( a=>
        { x = a.prop = newVal; y = a.prop2 = newVal2; return x; };`

     (Actually in [Linq to objects Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658028/linq-to-objects-update) there is a suggestion to refactor this last method into an extension method, which will allow it to use in a query expression, as well as clarify the intention).